# Increment, display, and print a number of pages up to a Parameter maximum

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to set up a Crystal Report to generate pallet labels which include a "Pallet N of M" line on each page.

The order in the database only has one entry, which contains all of the other information for the label(s).  My issue is that the number of pallets isn't known until print time, and each label needs the same order information as well as a pallet ID.  What I am looking for is for the user to enter a parameter for the total number of pallets, then have Crystal generate the correct number of unique labels.

For example, if the order has 4 pallets then Crystal should generate 4 copies of the label, the only difference on each copy being the last line which should read 'Pallet 1 of 4', 'Pallet 2 of 4', 'Pallet 3 of 4', and 'Pallet 4 of 4' respectively.

The only solution I can think of would be to create a number of sections equal to the maximum number of pallets, all containing my real data as a sub-report, then suppress any which are greater than the entered parameter.  I am trying to avoid this because we may have greater than 50 pallets on a given order, so that would be tedious to create and is just not a very clean solution.

-= EDIT =-

Big thanks to Aliqux for the solution.  In the end I needed to change the syntax to be Oracle compatible and also include the LINKVALUE field in the report, but the answer was 99% there especially considering I had not mentioned that my datasource was Oracle.  The Command syntax I ended up using (with my parameter called TotalPallets) was:

SELECT 
-1 AS "LINKVALUE"
FROM table
WHERE rownum <= {?TotalPallets}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to Add a command to your tables.

1) Under database Expert in the Database you used select Add Command.

2) Click create to Create a Parameter.

3) Create the requested values, you can leave the Default Value blank if you want, and change the Value Type to Number. (I will be calling my parameter Counter)

4) Put the following in the SQL query where table is the main table you are using

```
SELECT TOP {?Counter}
-1  AS LINKVALUE
FROM table
```

5) Click okay and enter a value if prompted

6) In links link a number field, that will never go into negative numbers as we are using -1 for a base, to the LINKVALUE in the Command Table.

7)Link Options are as followed

Join Type: Inner Join, Enforce Join: Not Enforced, Link Type: !=

8) In your report create a formula with a shared numbervalue the starts from one.

```
shared numbervar counters;
if counters = {?Counter} then counters := 0;
counters := counters + 1
```

9) You can use that formula and the Counter Parameter for your labels

```
totext({@Counts},0,"")+" of "+totext({?Counter},0,"")
```

Credit reference: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/01/24/duplicating-data-details-records-n-times-eg-repeating-labels-n-times/

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I was attempting to try this today and I am getting an error when I try and add the command.  My datasource is an Oracle database so maybe it is just a synax issue, but the error I am getting is:

Comment: "Failed to retreive data from the database.  Details: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected [Database Vendor Code: 923]

Comment: Looks like I was able to get it to work by using this syntax instead:
SELECT
-1  AS "LINKVALUE"
FROM ORDERHDR
WHERE rownum <= {?TotalPallets}

Comment: I should clarify, I had used TotalPallets for my parameter instead of Counter.  One additional step that was required was that I needed to place the LINKVALUE field in the report, otherwise I was getting only the first page.  Once I added it to a suppressed section it worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!